# How to get certfile (.android\emulator-grpc.cer)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

After updating java, this message appears every time I run the emulator

```
21:13   Emulator: emulator: WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot find certfile: C:\Users\Aml\.android\emulator-grpc.cer 

security will be disabled.

21:13   Emulator: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554
```

Did some one face this issue and do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem with you in Android Studio 3.6.1. I think it is a bug in this version. I solved this problem by downgrading the Android studio to 3.5.3. You can find previous versions from here: https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.htm