# How to fix GRPC Error “WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot find certfile” when I start the emulator?

Tags: android

> Emulator: emulator: WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot find
>   certfile: C:\Users....android\emulator-grpc.cer security will be
>   disabled.
>
> Emulator: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554

Does someone know a solution?

Comment: It doesn't work with only the default code i didn't write anything else..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get certfile (.android\emulator-grpc.cer)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60344740/how-to-get-certfile-android-emulator-grpc-cer)

Answer (score 1):

Please wipe the data of your virtual device from

> AVD manager -> your virtual devices -> wipe data

[You can view Screenshot of the following android studio window from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1n11.jpg)